# Facebook Open Graph: defining objects and actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a Facebook app where people can predict soccer matches. What I'd like is a notification system that says something like:

```
'Friend A' predicted a 3-2 score on 'Match A'
```

or

```
'Friend A' predicted:
- Match A: 3-2
- Match B: 0-0
```

And display these updates to friends of the player. Is this possibile? I can't get any further than:

```
'Friend A' predicted 'Match A'.
```

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

You can only use two parameters in publishing actions, a `object` and a `action`. In your case, the action is `predicted` and object is `match`. You cannot add the third `score` variable in for what you are trying to achieve. Maybe the [Score API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/) can help you achieve what you want to do.